# Extracting only the month and year in R

Tags: r, date

I want to extract only the month and year of this output, may i know how do you do that using R?

```
op_date_2 <- as.Date(data$op_date, "%d-%b-%y")

[1] "1992-01-01" "1992-01-02" "1992-01-02" "1992-01-02" "1992-01-02" "1992-01-02" "1992-01-03" "1992-01-05" "1992-01-07" "1992-01-09"
[11] "1992-01-09" "1992-01-10" "1992-01-10" "1992-01-10" "1992-01-14" "1992-01-14" "1992-01-16" "1992-01-16" "1992-01-16" "1992-01-21"
[21] "1992-01-21" "1992-01-23" "1992-01-28" "1992-01-30" "1992-01-30" "1992-01-30" "1992-02-01" "1992-02-01" "1992-02-02" "1992-02-04"
```

Comment: `format(op_date_2, "%m-%Y")` ?

Comment: It's not clear how your example code relates to the example output? The output is `%Y-%m-%d`, the code uses `%d-%b-%y`. It would help to include some or all of `data`, using plain text, in your question.

Comment: @RonakShah For many reasons, it would generally be desirable to put the year followed by the month.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the **lubridate** library. First transform your data and then retrieve month and year.

```
library(lubridate)
Test <- c("1992-01-01", "1992-01-02", "1994-03-02")
TestData <- as.POSIXlt(Test, format="%Y-%m-%d")
YourMonths <- month(TestData)
YourMonths
YourYears <- year(TestData)
YourYears
```

Comment: You can use `ymd` from `lubridate`: `TestData <- ymd(Test)`